# ZF2 Doctrine: Use data from another entity in a form

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

in ZF2 I've got a form which edits the data of a table in the database. I'd like to add a field from another table to the form, how can I do it?

The table is called **UserProfile**, the entity Class goes like this:

```
namespace UpvUser\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; 
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter; 
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;  
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface; 

/**
* User Profile
*
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="userprofile")
* @property int $userId
* @property string $title
* @property string $firstName
* @property string $lastName
and so on...
*/

class UserProfile
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    public $userId;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    public $title;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    public $firstName;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
and so on including getters/setters and input filters...
```

The UserProfileForm class goes like this:

```
namespace UpvUser\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;

class UserProfileForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct('userprofile');               // The name of the form
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'userId',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'hidden',
            ),
        ));        
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'title',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'firstName',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
            ),
        ));
// and so on...
```

and in the editAction() of the controller I have:

```
$user = $this->getEntityManager()->find('UpvUser\Entity\UserProfile', $userId);

$form  = new UserProfileForm();
$form->bind($user);
$form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'LANG_BTN_EDIT');

$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->isPost()) {
    $form->setInputFilter($user->getInputFilter());
    $form->setData($request->getPost());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('upv-user', array('action' => 'overview'));           // Redirect to list of albums
    }
 }

 return array(
     'userId' => $userId,
     'form' => $form,
 );
```

I guess the **$form->bind($user)** populates the form with the data from **$user** object, but how can I append other data, e.g. user's e-mail address, which is stored in another table called **User** (which has the corresponding structure and Entity class as well), in a column **e-mail**, with the same **id** as the **userprofile.userid**? I tried to make a getter to another table from UserProfile entity class, but the Entity manager is only available in the controller and not in Entity classes! Or should I do it in the controller and somehow append the missing data to the **$user** object (but I guess I *should* make it in the model and not in the controller)? Or do I **have** to define a foreign key between the two tables, even if the user id is the same (but I'm not allowed to change the *User* table, it's used as a shared resource for the other ones as well)?

Thanks a lot for info

Jan

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with Fieldsets - just make an own Fieldset for the second Entity (note the **setObject()** call) and be sure to set the name the same as it is defined in your entity class (parent::__construct()). Example: 'user' -> is your referencing/relating entity property (from where you need the 'external' data) - sorry I can't explain it better.

```
class UserDataFieldset extends Fieldset {

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager){

        parent::__construct('user');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager))
             ->setObject(new UserData());

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'email',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
            ),
        ));

        // etc....
    }
}
```

In your Form you can add it like a normal form-element:

```
class UserProfileForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager, $name = null)
    {
        // etc..

        $this->add(new UserDataFieldset($objectManager));
    }
}
```

that should be enough.